# Accessing the components in a custom cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table using custom cells, within a custom cell i have a picker and a textfield.

I have a custom class for the cell that has outlets for these elements.

In the parent VC of the table I want to be able to reference the contensts of the text field and the value of the picker.

How do i gain access to these values when they are in a custom cell rather than just on the main viewcontroller view?

Code for cell:

```
    class NewExerciseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

    @IBOutlet weak var setNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var repsPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userExerciseWeight: UITextField!

}
```

I tried to access it by creating `let setCell = NewExerciseTableViewCell()` and then trying to access its contents components via its properties, but thats not the way to do it!

Appreciate any assistance here on how I can pull out the values in this cell!

edit: here is my callForRowAt

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? NewExerciseTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    return cell
}
```

Comment: study about  UITableViews in swift you will get your answer.

Comment: • Use a custom class (reference type) as model. • Pass the data source item to the cell in `cellForRowAt`. • Update the data source item in the cell. • Later get the data from the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object of `UITableViewCell` with the type of your custom type. Let say you are making a table view then you can add the cells in cellForRowAt. See below code for reference

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewExerciseTableViewCell
        cell.setNumber.text = // Some Value
}
```

In the above method the cell is now of type `NewExerciseTableViewCell` and you can now access any public property of that class.

If you want to get the values of particular cell then you will need to get the cell first. Check the below code for reference

```
let cell = yourTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NewExerciseTableViewCell
print(cell.setNumber.text)
```

Comment: So to pull the values from the cell contents id want to create var's in the VC and set them via, for example, self.userWeight = Int(cell.userExerciseWeight.text!)

Comment: First you need to find the index of the cell for which you are looking the data  and then get the cell from that index with the above method I mentioned then yes you can fetch the data as you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, out of interest how do i access the cell outside of the cellforrowat? or cant i do that, e.g. i want to save the cells contents into core data when a  save button is pressed so i want to access its properties from a different func

Comment: The second part gives the answer to your question.

Comment: 'indexPath' isnt recognised outside of that function, its unique to the tablerow related funcs?

Comment: @jwarris91 You need to find out yourself which row data you want? If you want to store all data to core data have a loop for that.

Comment: yes i want to store all the rows but as their own entities, so i need to loop the rows and perform the save for each yes?

Comment: Yes you can loop through all the rows to save also you can find the better and efficient solution.

Comment: how do you mean better and efficient? i assumed looping would be most effective?

Answer (score 0):

This question contains multiple parts, and I'll try to address them one by one.

1- First of all if you want to set the values, properties, etc. you have to do that in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method.
(Set the `cellIdentifer` in your storyboard.)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIndetifier", for: indexPath) as! NewExerciseTableViewCell
    cell.setNumber.text = "1"
    ...
    return cell
}
```

2- You cannot access cell's subview just by creating a new one. That doesn't make sense. Use `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: ...)` and then you have a valid `cell.setNumber`

P.S. btw the `setNumber` is not a good practice for naming a label. Use `set` only for `setter` methods.

Comment: Thanks i have updated the OP with my proposed method. setNumber is actually a reference to exercise sets, but ill rename it to avoid confusion. So now i just need to use the let cell =   method to select parts of it?

Comment: @jwarris91 so the first part of my answer is irrelevant now as you are already doing it. Use the second part when you want to extract the data from a given cell at a defined indexPath

Comment: thanks and how would i address something like the picker which needs methods to set its self up, as i cant create these functions within that cell function to handle its setup?

Comment: I think you need to use delegation for that

Comment: yes that was my thought, so id set the cell.picker.delegate to be the view controller

Comment: that may cause some problems if you have multiple cells of this class. create a protocol for you cell class, set `cell.delegate = vc` and `picker.delegate  = cell`. This way you can also pass the info of the cell to vc